# Print CSS refuses to hide elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using simple CSS with modern browsers: IE 9 and Firefox 10.

```
<link href="/css/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

With this content it works.

```
@media print
{
    #wrap, div.push, div.footer, div.barra_sopra_datatables, div.fg-toolbar, img{
        display: none;
    }   

    body {
        font-size: 10pt;
    }

     * {  
     margin: 0;  
     padding: 0;  
    }  


}
```

I need to hide some columns of a table, so just for testing I tried

```
tr:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

but it hides **all** the tr elements.

I’ve alsove also tried `td:first-child` and `table tbody tr td:first-child` and other selectors, and **all of them fail**. I need to maintain compatibility with IE 8. [kimblim.dk](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/) says that IE 8 supports these selectors, so why won’t it work? I’m not trying to set background color which many pointed out doesn’t work.

Comment: What's your table HTML? Does the same style work correctly in other media besides print?

Comment: Also, if you need to "hide some columns", trying to hide a row won't do the trick.

Comment: I just tested in IE8 (the real one, not IE9 in compatibility mode) and I cannot reproduce your problem. Both the `@media print` part and the `td:first-child {display:none;}` part work fine. So can you post a link to your website? I need to see if there's other things going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot just don't display table cells.
`display:none` means, don't display it at all, so do as it would not have been there in the first place. Perhaps the browser thinks, if the first column is not there anymore, the next column is the new first one and then it hide this columns as well.

Try to give a table-cell a class `hide-in-print` and then

```
@media print {
  .hide-in-print {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Maybe `@media print` is not supported fully by IE. If this is true, try conditional comments.

Comment: No, it all works fine on IE8. Something else must be going on that causes the OP's problem.